# Class specific nth-of-type(odd)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I found a CSS tutorial to style a table, but on my page there are other tables. So I cannot figure out how to use a selector here. `tr:nth-of-type(odd)` is the selector. But I want this to be used only on a table which has an `id` or `class` named `playerslist`.

```
<table id="playerslist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Player #</th>
            <th>Team</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Simon</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>Team A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Richard</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Team B</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas how to target `tr:nth-of-type(odd)`, `th` and `td` elements of a table with an `id` of `playerslist`?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify your table's class or id in your style definition:

```
table#playerslist tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
   // your styles
}
```

Comment: I would not call that idea, it's pretty basic :) If you find a minute, learn a bit about [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 4):

To target the `tr:nth-of-type(odd)` elements of a `table` with an `id` or `class` called `playerslist`, use

```
table#playerslist tr:nth-of-type(odd), 
table.playerslist tr:nth-of-type(odd)
 {/* styling */}
```

To target the `th` and `td` elements of a `table` having `id='playerslist'`, use

```
table#playerslist th, 
table#playerslist td {/* styling */}
```